# Service Account Types Supported for SQL Server Agent and SQL Server Analysis

Tags: sql-server, ssas, account

I am taking a Windows Azure introductory course and one of the prerrequisites for it is to have installed SQL Server 2008 R2 on my machine.

When I'm installing SQL Server in the Server Configuration section it asks for 2 users: one for the **SQL Server Agent** and other one for the **SQL Server Analysis**.

I am a begginer, so that's why I'm asking you to recommend me **wich users should I use**. And also, is it possible to **change the users after installation**?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can change the user after you install those services. The services will run using those accounts and therefore the services will have the same rights as the accounts.
For DEV/test you can use the local system account.
For production you should create a dedicated domain account for those services.

Answer (score 0):

[The best account to use in this instance would be The Network Service Account.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143504%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Be aware that the Local Service account is not supported for the SQL Server or SQL Server Agent services.

The Network Service account is a built-in account that has more access to resources and objects than members of the Users group. Services that run as the Network Service account access network resources by using the credentials of the computer account. The actual name of the account is "NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE".

Network Service Account is the only account which is supported by SQL Server and SQL Server Agent Services, allows for network file system access i.e. SSMS DBA tasks, and yet still avoids using a Local System Account.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143504(v=sql.105).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143504%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

[To change which account the service runs under](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345578.aspx), do so in the same GUI that you are currently using inside SQL Server Configuration Manager